# Logo text vs. image

Tags: image, web

Right now, I see a lot of website they use text logo replace image logo. What is different between text and image on the our website? If you any one have any idea please share.

Example:

- http://getbootstrap.com/
- https://ghost.org/

Inspect element on logo for both websites above. I saw they use text not image for they logo.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

A good reason to use text instead of an image is SEO (search engine optimization).

Search engines will look for text in the `<h1>` element as one of the strongest indicators for what the page contains. If you don't have an `<h1>` element, or if it just contains an image, the search engine will be less sure of what the page contains.

Pages with a `<title>` and an `<h1>` that are at least partially equal, have a better chance to make good search results.

One way to have a nice image as logo and still present the text to the search engines, is to put text in the `<h1>` element, then use CSS to hide the text and show an image instead.